# How to replace some special characters?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a PHP code that will connect to a database, select a table and then get data from it. In one of my colums (That named **title**), i have data looks like: `Hello World - This/That is (Test)`
But i want to **convert** this to this: `hello-world-this-that-is-test`
Because i want to use this kind of text in my **page's URL**.

I mean i need to

1. Remove spaces
2. Remove double or multiple dashes
3. Remove slash and backslash
4. Remove brackets like ( and )

and want to replace all of them with only one dash as i wrote above. in other word i want to delete all special characters and convert them to only one dash

Currently my code can remove space and double dashes, but it can't remove slashes and brackets. here is my code:

```
<?php 
 define('DBHOST','localhost');
 define('DBUSER','user');
 define('DBPASS','pass');
 define('DBNAME','name');

$db = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
if(!$db){
 die( "Sorry! There seems to be a problem connecting to our database.");
}

$myFile = "sitemap.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
$rss_txt = null;

$rss_txt .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$rss_txt .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">';

$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM posts_articles ORDER BY post_id ASC");
while($values_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rss_txt .= '<url>';
    $rss_txt .= '<loc>https://example.com/blogs/'.$values_query["post_id"].'/'.$var = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", "-", $values_query["title"]).'</loc>';
    $rss_txt .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
    $rss_txt .= '<priority>0.7</priority>';
    $rss_txt .= '</url>';
}

$rss_txt .= '</urlset>';

fwrite($fh, $rss_txt);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

OK. This part of my code have to get **title** `'.$var = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", "-", $values_query["title"]).'` this code can remove space and multi dashes to only one dash. USEFUL! But if title column have brackets or slashes, it can't remove them and my code will fail.

I'm very very new to PHP and SQL so don't blame me. i have to start learning but after reading over 50 articles, i couldn't find anything useful to do what i want.

Comment: Regular expressions are hard. Maybe try something like this: preg_replace("/([\s\(\)\/\-])+(\-?)+/", "-", $values_query["title"]); I have only testet it on https://regex101.com

Comment: If your problem is to do with string manipulation, focus on that. We don't need all the code that retrieves data from a database. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses three separate regular expressions to do successive transformations to the string:

```
<?php

$regex1 = "/[^0-9a-z\s]+/i";        // Search for everything that is not alphanumeric or whitespace
$regex2 = "/\s+/";                  // Search for whitespace
$regex3 = "/-+$/";                  // search for trailing dashes

$text = "Hello World - This/That is (Test)";

// replace in turn, non-alpha with space, one or more spaces with dash,
// one or more trailing dashes with nothing 
$text2 = preg_replace([$regex1, $regex2, $regex3],[' ','-',''], $text);

// Switch everything to lower case
$text2 = strtolower($text2);

echo $text2;       // hello-world-this-that-is-test
```

Demo:https://3v4l.org/Pe5hC

(The regex purists might be able to condense this further, but this is clear and easily modifiable)